# angularjs unable to assign scope variable inside link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have the following snippet of code. My objective is to allow the creation of multiple divs and their position, text, height and width are binded to the controller's model.

```
appModule.controller('textController', function($scope){
    var box = {x: '0', y: '0', height: '100px', width: '200px', text: 'this is the default text'};

    $scope.textBoxes = [box];

    $scope.addNewTextBox = function(){
        console.log("creating new textbox!!!");
        $scope.textBoxes.push(box);
    };
});

appModule.directive('tbox', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true, 
        scope: {
            model: "=",
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){ //the scope here is the object's scope
            var length = scope.$parent.textBoxes.length;
            console.log(length);
            scope.model = scope.$parent.textBoxes[length-1];
        }
    }

});
```

I ran into some problems here. I am unable assign the scope's model variable to the textBoxes variable in the controller, saying

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: tbox)
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:43:213)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:43:326)
    at Object.e.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:87:13)
    at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:89:198)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js:16:239
    at Object.d [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have an object called `model` on the parent scope?  I'm wondering if it's stumbling on the binding in your `scope` attribute.

Comment: @KayakDave, nope, do i need to? I'm sorry but Im still abit fuzzy about the concepts of isolated scopes. I did my modification from this http://plnkr.co/edit/VFbP9h though

Comment: Well, your '=' within the `scope` is asking to bind to an object called `model` since you don't specify anything on the right of the equal sign.  Do you need the `=` at all?

Comment: hmm i actually interpret that as whenever that object's x,y change when I drag it, the controller's model also change. thats my objective. Does that qualify?

Comment: Yep, looking at your code I see you do have a model object where you're storing x and y.  So yea, looks good.  The plnkr seems to be working for me- did you resolve the issue?

Comment: the plnker was someone's else code which i took and modify. My code was the one above which doesnt work. Do u mean to say I need to create a object called model? Where should it be? Controller, directive or both?

Comment: It needs be declared on the parent scope that the directive will live in.  The directive is going to look for an object on the parent scope called 'model' and bind to it, so then both the parent and directive will have access to it.  (personally I'd change the name to something more descriptive- if you do change the name, make sure to change the name on the left side of the equal sign also).

Comment: Looking more, try just removing the 'model: "=",', you may not even need it the way you're going.  Hard to be sure without seeing all your code

Comment: hi KayakDave, sorry for the late response. Yup remove model solves my problem. would u like to put it as the answer so i can check it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is reporting that 'model' is undefined try removing `model: "="` from the directive's isolate scope.

So it'll look like this:

```
scope: {},
```